# Image picker not get file Flutter

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-dependencies

the flutter code below allows me to select an image from the gallery and insert it in a variable File file, but when I run the code and try to print the file value it is always null, how do I solve this?

**Dart code:**

```
Future getImage() async {
    PickedFile pickedFile = await ImagePicker().getImage(
      source: ImageSource.gallery,
    );
    if (pickedFile != null) {
      print("file picked");
      file = File(pickedFile.path);
    }
    else{
      print("File not picked");
    }

  }
```

**Full class code:**

```
File file;
class DocumentiImpiantoView extends StatefulWidget {
  const DocumentiImpiantoView(this.imp);
  final Impianto imp;
  @override
  _DocumentiImpiantoViewState createState() => _DocumentiImpiantoViewState();
}

class _DocumentiImpiantoViewState extends State<DocumentiImpiantoView> {
  TextEditingController _searchController = new TextEditingController();
  Timer timer;

  final picker = ImagePicker();

  _DocumentiImpiantoViewState() {
    timer = Timer.periodic(Duration(seconds: 6), (Timer t) => updateui());
    getData();
  }

  Future<bool> getData() async {
    listadocumenti = await Documento.load(widget.imp);
    return true;
  }

  Future getImage() async {
    PickedFile pickedFile = await ImagePicker().getImage(
      source: ImageSource.gallery,
    );
    if (pickedFile != null) {
      print("file picked");
      file = File(pickedFile.path);
    }
    else{
      print("File not picked");
    }

  }

  updateui() async {
    var values = await Documento.load(widget.imp);
    setState(() {
      listadocumenti = values;
    });
  }

  selectfile() async {
    print("Seleziono il file");
    FilePickerResult result = await FilePicker.platform.pickFiles();
    if (result != null) {
      print("Salvataggio file");
       file = File(result.files.single.path);
    } else {
      // User canceled the picker
    }
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return FutureBuilder<bool>(
      future: getData(),
      builder: (BuildContext context, AsyncSnapshot<bool> snapshot) {
        return !snapshot.hasData
            ? new Container()
            : Scaffold(
                body: getBody(),
              );
      },
    );
  }

  //Funzione che apre la visualizzazione del file con link
  openfile() {
    //await launch(URL, forceSafariVC: false);
  }

  goback(BuildContext context) {
    final gr = new DettagliImpiantoView(widget.imp);
    Navigator.pushReplacement(context, MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => gr));
  }

  //Upload file su impianto
  uploadfile() async {
    print("caricamento file");
    if(file==null){
      print("File è null");
    }
    else {
      try {
        //List<int> fileInByte = file.readAsBytesSync();
        final bytes = File(file.path).readAsBytesSync();
        String base64Image = "data:image/png;base64," + base64Encode(bytes);
        print("caricamento file 2");
        Impianto.uploadfile(widget.imp, base64Image, file.path);
        updateui();
      } catch (err) {
        print("Errore: " + err);
      }
    }
  }

  Widget getBody() {
    return SafeArea(
        child: ListView(
      padding: EdgeInsets.only(left: 20, right: 20, top: 15),
      children: <Widget>[
        Row(
          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
          children: <Widget>[
            GestureDetector(
              onTap: () {
                goback(context);
              },
              child: Icon(Icons.arrow_back),
            ),
            Text(
              "Documenti",
              style: TextStyle(fontSize: 22, fontWeight: FontWeight.bold),
            ),
            Icon(Icons.add)
          ],
        ),
        SizedBox(
          height: 10,
        ),
        SizedBox(
          height: 30,
        ),
        SingleChildScrollView(
          scrollDirection: Axis.horizontal,
          child: Row(
            children: <Widget>[
              Padding(
                padding: EdgeInsets.only(right: 20),
                child: Column(
                  children: <Widget>[
                    GestureDetector(
                      onTap: () {
                        uploadfile();
                      },
                      child: Container(
                        width: 70,
                        height: 70,
                        decoration: BoxDecoration(shape: BoxShape.circle, color: grey),
                        child: Center(
                          child: Icon(
                            LineIcons.plus,
                            size: 33,
                          ),
                        ),
                      ),
                    ),
                    SizedBox(
                      height: 10,
                    ),
                    GestureDetector(
                        onTap: () {
                          uploadfile();
                        },
                        child: SizedBox(
                          width: 75,
                          child: Align(
                              child: Text(
                            'Upload File',
                            overflow: TextOverflow.ellipsis,
                          )),
                        )),
                  ],
                ),
              ),
              Row(
                  children: List.generate(optionsList.length, (index) {
                return Padding(
                  padding: const EdgeInsets.only(right: 20),
                  child: Column(
                    children: <Widget>[
                      GestureDetector(
                        onTap: () {
                          if (optionsList[index]["name"] == "Documenti") {
                            selectfile();
                          } else {
                            getImage();
                          }
                        },
                        child: Container(
                          width: 75,
                          height: 75,
                          child: Stack(
                            children: <Widget>[
                              Container(
                                  decoration: BoxDecoration(
                                      shape: BoxShape.circle, border: Border.all(color: blue_story, width: 3)),
                                  child: Padding(
                                    padding: const EdgeInsets.all(3.0),
                                    child: Container(
                                      width: 90,
                                      height: 90,
                                      child: ClipRRect(
                                        borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(8.0),
                                        child: Image.asset(optionsList[index]['img'], width: 30, height: 30),
                                      ),
                                    ),
                                  )),
                              Positioned(
                                top: 48,
                                left: 52,
                                child: Container(
                                  width: 20,
                                  height: 20,
                                  decoration: BoxDecoration(
                                      color: online,
                                      shape: BoxShape.circle,
                                      border: Border.all(color: white, width: 3)),
                                ),
                              ),
                            ],
                          ),
                        ),
                      ),
                      SizedBox(
                        height: 10,
                      ),
                      SizedBox(
                        width: 90,
                        child: Align(
                            child: Text(
                          optionsList[index]['name'],
                          overflow: TextOverflow.ellipsis,
                        )),
                      )
                    ],
                  ),
                );
              }))
            ],
          ),
        ),
        SizedBox(
          height: 30,
        ),
        Column(
          children: List.generate(listadocumenti.length, (index) {
            return InkWell(
              onTap: () {},
              child: Padding(
                padding: const EdgeInsets.only(bottom: 20),
                child: Row(
                  children: <Widget>[
                    Container(
                      width: 75,
                      height: 75,
                      child: Stack(
                        children: <Widget>[
                          Container(
                            decoration:
                                BoxDecoration(shape: BoxShape.circle, border: Border.all(color: blue_story, width: 3)),
                            child: Padding(
                              padding: const EdgeInsets.all(3.0),
                              child: Container(
                                width: 90,
                                height: 90,
                                child: ClipRRect(
                                  borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(8.0),
                                  child: Image.asset("assets/images/rapportini.png"),
                                ),
                              ),
                            ),
                          ),
                          Positioned(
                            top: 48,
                            left: 52,
                            child: Container(
                              width: 20,
                              height: 20,
                              decoration: BoxDecoration(
                                  color: online, shape: BoxShape.circle, border: Border.all(color: white, width: 3)),
                            ),
                          )
                        ],
                      ),
                    ),
                    SizedBox(
                      width: 20,
                    ),
                    Column(
                      crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                      children: <Widget>[
                        Text(
                          listadocumenti[index].Utente,
                          style: TextStyle(fontSize: 17, fontWeight: FontWeight.w500),
                        ),
                        SizedBox(
                          height: 5,
                        ),
                        SizedBox(
                          width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width - 135,
                          child: Text(
                            listadocumenti[index].IdDoc.toString(),
                            style: TextStyle(fontSize: 15, color: black.withOpacity(0.8)),
                            overflow: TextOverflow.ellipsis,
                          ),
                        )
                      ],
                    )
                  ],
                ),
              ),
            );
          }),
        )
      ],
    ));
  }
}
```

Comment: Where did you print `file`?

Comment: i'm not print file, check if it is selected on the function uploadfile @Josteve

Answer (score 0):

In your code there are several issues. First of all imagePicker picks image as Xfile but you are assigning it as File. Edit your getImage function like this one. Sometime it may an issue if the image size is too large. In that case compress image may help you.

```
File? _imageFile;
Future<void> getImage() async {
 XFile? pickedFile = await ImagePicker().pickImage(source: ImageSource.gallery);
 if (pickedFile != null) {
   File selected = File(pickedFile.path);
  _imageFile = selected;
  compressFile(_imageFile!);
 }
}
```

compress file function

```
Future<void> compressFile(File file) async {
 if (file.lengthSync() < 1000000) {
  setState(() {
    _imageFile = file;
  });
} else {
ImageProperties properties =
    await FlutterNativeImage.getImageProperties(file.path);
    File result = await FlutterNativeImage.compressImage(file.path,
    quality: 95,
    targetWidth: 600,
    targetHeight: (properties.height! * 600 / 
    properties.width!).round());
    setState(() {
     _imageFile = result;
   });
 }
NavigationService.getCurrentState()?.pop(_imageFile);
}
```

Comment: i not have method pickImage i have getimage

Comment: I have used pickImage because getImage is now deprecated. It is always a good practice to use updated packages.